# Como publico en mi muro de fecebook utilizando graph api de facebook

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Hé intentado hacer publicar en mi muro de facebook con lo que se muestra en la imagen con en id de mi perfil pero no puedo hacerlo. ¿Alguien que haya pasado por esto? Cabe recalcar que tengo marcadas todas las opciones del usuario.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hola para poder publicar en tu perfil debes solicitar un **token de acceso** con el permiso `publish_actions` , para ello debes enviar tu aplicación a revisión y si te la aprueban podrás conseguirlo y publicar

Answer (score 1):

Hola amigo acá te dejo algunos métodos POST para publicar en facebook que se ejecutan directamente en el navegador, es lo mismo que usar el Explorador de la API Graph

saludos!!

1 - ENLACE PARA PUBLICAR UN ESTADO

```
https ://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?
method=post
&message=ACA SE ESCRIBE EL MENSAJE
&access_token=/////
```

2 - ENLACE PARA PUBLICAR UN LINK (ejemplo Youtube)

```
https ://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?
method=post
&message=MENSAJE
&caption=DESCRIPCION 1
&description=DESCRIPCION 2
&link=https ://www.youtube.com/
&access_token=/////
```

3 - ENLACE PARA SUBIR UNA FOTO desde URL

```
https ://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?
method=post
&message=ACA SE ESCRIBE UN MENSAJE
&url=https ://www.URLdelaIMAGENparaSUBIR.jpg
&access_token=/////
```

4 - ENLACE PARA SUBIR UN VIDEO desde URL

```
https ://graph-video.facebook.com/videos?
method=post
&message=MENSAJE
&url=https ://www.URLdelVIDEOparaSUBIR.mp4
&access_token=/////
```

5 - ENLACE PARA COMENTAR

```
https ://graph.facebook.com/NUMERO_ID_POST/comments?
method=post
&message=ACA SE ESCRIBE EL COMENTARIO
&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

6 - ENLACE PARA PONER ME GUSTA

```
https ://graph.facebook.com/NUMERO_ID_POST/likes?
method=post
&access_token=/////
```

7 - ENLACE PARA PONER REACCIONES

```
https ://graph. facebook. com/NUMERO_ID_POST/reactions?
summary=true
&method=post
&type=XXXX puede ser entre (LIKE, LOVE, WOW, HAHA, SAD, ANGRY, THANKFUL, PRIDE, CARE)
&access_token=/////
```

8 - ENLACE PARA PUBLICAR UN ESTADO

```
https:// api. facebook. com/method/stream.publish?
message=MENSAJE
&target_id=100045625414217
&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

9 - ENLACE PARA PUBLICAR UN LINK (ejemplo taringa)

```
https:// api. facebook. com/method/stream.publish?
message=MENSAJE
&link= https: //www. taringa. net/ 
&target_id=100045625414217
&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

10 - ENLACE PARA COMENTAR

```
https:// api. facebook. com/method/stream.addComment?
comment=ACA SE ESCRIBE EL COMENTARIO
&post_id=NUMERO_ID_POST
&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

11 - ENLACE PARA PONER ME GUSTA

```
https:// api. facebook. com/method/stream.addLike?
&post_id=NUMERO_ID_POST
&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

12 - ENLACE PARA PUBLICAR UN LINK + VISTA PREVIA

```
https: //api. facebook. com/method/stream.publish?
message=hola
&attachment={
    'name':'','href':' https: //www. taringa. net/',
    "media":[{
        "type":"image",
        "src":" https: //www. taringa. net/Thumbnail.jpg",
        "href":" https: //www. taringa. net/"
        }]}
&target_id=100045625414217
&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```